# Firebase and Expo: Database add child and remove it immediately

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I'm creating a conference app (like f8 app) with Expo and Firebase.

The component "TalkInfo" have a function `addOrRemoveUserTalk(loggedUser, talk)`, that is triggered when you touch Like/Dislike button of some Talk, and the state "buttonText" could be that "Like" or "Dislike" text in the button:

- If `this.state.buttonText == 'Dislike'` when you click the button the app remove the "userTalk" from db
- and if `this.state.buttonText == 'Like'`the app create the "userTalk" for the user.

I have an issue: I can add a userTalk in db, and I can remove it, BUT if I add the same userTalk again, firebase add it, and remove it immediately

Please someone who masters firebase can help me?

```
addOrRemoveUserTalk(loggedUser, talk) {
  var text = 'Like';

  if(this.state.buttonText == 'Dislike') {
    firebaseApp.database().ref().child('userTalks')
      .orderByChild('user')
      .equalTo(loggedUser.uid)
      .on('child_added', (snap) => {
        userTalk = snap.val();
        if(userTalk.talk == talk.id) {
          text = 'Like';
          console.log("CHILD WILL BE DESTROYED");
          snap.ref.remove();
        }
      })
  } else {
    text = 'Dislike';
    console.log("CHILD WILL BE ADDED");
    firebaseApp.database().ref().child('userTalks').push({
      user: loggedUser.uid,
      talk: talk.id,
    }).key;
  }

  console.log("text in addOrRemoveUserTalk_________", text);

  text == 'Like' ?
    this.setState({ buttonText: 'Like' }) :
    this.setState({ buttonText: 'Dislike' })
}
```

Comment: You should using once rather than on

Comment: Thanks, it works! little difference, big impact on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now whenever you first "like" a post, you add a listener that stays "forever" active. What you want instead is to just read the value once, and then stop monitoring it. As digit commented, you'll want to use `once()` instead of `on()`.

```
if(this.state.buttonText == 'Dislike') {
  firebaseApp.database().ref().child('userTalks')
    .orderByChild('user')
    .equalTo(loggedUser.uid)
    .once('child_added', (snap) => {
      userTalk = snap.val();
      if(userTalk.talk == talk.id) {
        text = 'Like';
        console.log("CHILD WILL BE DESTROYED");
        snap.ref.remove();
      }
    })
} else {
  text = 'Dislike';
  console.log("CHILD WILL BE ADDED");
  firebaseApp.database().ref().child('userTalks').push({
    user: loggedUser.uid,
    talk: talk.id,
  }).key;
}
```